# Outputting SQL Data to a Text File with Python - How to get rid of None?

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x

I’m pulling data from a SQL Server table using pyodbc python code.

In the output file I’m getting records like this:

1, 1, None, None, None, None, None, None

The None values are Null in the SQL table.

I’d like to see records in the text file in this format.  I do not want to see the None.

1, 1, , , , , ,

Any ideas how I can do this?

### Here is the code I'm using:

```
    import pyodbc

    outputfile = 'MyOut.txt'

    output_data = open(outputfile, 'w+')

    conn=pyodbc.connect(
        r'Driver={SQL Server};'
        r'Server=MyServer;’
        r'Database=MyData;'
        r'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

    crsr = conn.cursor()

    crsr.execute('select * from MyTable’)

    for row in crsr:
    print(str(row))
        outrows = str(row).strip('(')
        outrows = outrows.strip(')')
        output_data.write(outrows + '\n')

    output_data.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that `outrows` is a string, but this would probably be made easier with an list. Aside from that, the output is probably meant to be a string, since you're writing into a txt.
You could modify your `for` loop as such

```py
for row in crsr:
    outrows = str(row).strip("(").strip(")")
    line = outrows.split(",")
    # creating the array, by splitting the string at each comma
    for component in line:
        if component == " None":
            # with " " as there is most likely a space after the "," in the file
            line[line.index(component)] = ""
    file.write(",".join(line)+"\n")
```

I'm afraid I'm not particularly familiar with pyodbc, but I hope this was of help.